# My foreach statement is outputting 2 errors

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

When I try to output a table with a foreach statement, it outputs 2 errors saying that the MovieViewModel and the MovieVM dont exist.

This is part of the Index.cshtml file:

```
  @foreach (MovieViewModel item in MovieVM)
  {
    <tr>
      <td>@item.MovieName</td>
      <td>@item.MovieCategory</td>
      <td>@item.MovieYear
      <td>@item.MoviePrice</td>
    </tr>
  }
</table>
```

This is part of the MoviesController.cs file:

```
  List<MovieViewModel> MovieVM = new List<MovieViewModel>
  {
    new MovieViewModel {
      MovieID = movie.MovieID,
      MovieName = movie.MovieName,
      MovieDescription = movie.MovieDescription,
      MoviePrice = movie.MoviePrice,
      MovieCategory = movie.MovieCategory,
      MovieYear = movie.MovieYear
    },
  };

  return View(MovieVM);
}
```

It outputs these 2 errors about the `foreach`:

> "The type or namespace 'EmployeeViewModel' does not exist in the
>   namespace 'WebApplication3.Models '(are you missing an assembly
>   reference?)"

and

> "The name 'MovieVM' does not exist in the current context"

Comment: `MovieViewModel item in MovieVM` makes no sense. MovieVM was declared in your action method, not in the view. They are different contexts. I guess you probably want to access the model? In that case use `MovieViewModel item in Model`

Comment: As for the other error, the code you have shown doesn't mention `EmployeeViewModel` anywhere, so the problem must be coming from something you haven't shown. The error should have told you the line number on which it occurred. Anyway it sounds you like you maybe missing a `using` statement in your view. Either that or you made a typo and referenced the wrong class

Comment: You could add missing namespaces to `web.config` inside your views folder `<add namespace="Example.ViewModels" />`

Comment: I also cannot make out how you are getting `EmployeeViewModel` does not exist. Unless you have reference to that in your View or as @ADyson said has made a typo

Comment: I changed MovieVM to Model and that error disappeared, but the other one is still not fixed. it keeps saying that is missing a reference. Is it some     using    statement that is causing me this error?

Comment: We don't know for sure, because you haven't shown us the code where you try to use `EmployeeViewModel`. You've only shown us code which talks about `MovieViewModel` instead. We also don't know where you declared the `EmployeeViewModel` class (i.e. what its namespace is, what assembly it's in, or whether it even exists at all).

Comment: Im sorry, I forgot to change the name, the EmployeeViewModel was the old name of the file and the class. That file is now MovieViewModel. In this file, I only have the class "MovieViewModel" with a few public get/set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must define the model type in the view.

```
@model IEnumerable<MovieViewModel>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
   <tr>
    <td>@item.MovieName</td>
    <td>@item.MovieCategory</td>
    <td>@item.MovieYear</td>
    <td>@item.MoviePrice</td>
   </tr>
}
```

sample: https://dotnetfiddle.net/GA0yHD

Comment: My code is very simillar to yours, the only diference is that in the controller, I get the data from a database, its not custom. Is there anything I have to change for beeing database data? Maybe a directory or something?

Comment: Hi @DiogoTeixeira. The real difference is in the View. I declare an `IEnumerable<MovieViewModel>` as `@model` and make the foreach to the `Model`not `MovieVM`(your variable name). The View not know the variables declared in the controler.

Comment: I've already tried that a lot of times and the same error appears, i have the @model IEnumerable and i have the var item in model, but it still only outputs 1 record.

Comment: @DiogoTeixeira How many records returns the database? in the example you can see how render all the records https://dotnetfiddle.net/GA0yHD .
Now show 1 record not the previous error

Comment: an update, i was trying to create a details view and when i was trying to write the @model, it appeared only the class, isnt it supposed to appear the the model?

Comment: i have currently 3 records in the database, just to test

Comment: @DiogoTeixeira In a details view you must show only a model `@model MovieViewModel`. I don't understand what you mean by the class and not the model. A model is a class

Comment: im sorry, im just so confused. I´ve done everything you told me and what the people above told and its not working and i dont see any reason for that.

Comment: @DiogoTeixeira You only return 1 record. `SingleOrDefault` return 1 record or null if the condition is not met.

Comment: Wait, dont tell me this was the problem... im so mad. Then what should i put instead of SingleOrDefault?

Comment: @DiogoTeixeira you are filter by Id. If the database is fine, only can exist an record

Comment: ooh, then what should I do to make it output all the records of the database?

Comment: Hi @DiogoTeixeira. If you want all the records `db.MoviesData.ToList()` and then map the result to a MovieViewModel list with a foreach or use the Nuget AutoMapper.

Answer (score 0):

Does this DB connection have anything to do with the error?

```
 public ActionResult Index()
    {
        PAPEntities db = new PAPEntities();
        MoviesData movie = db.MoviesData.SingleOrDefault(x => x.MovieID == 1);

        List<MovieViewModels> MovieVM = new List<MovieViewModels>
            {
                new MovieViewModels {
                 MovieID = movie.MovieID,
                 MovieName = movie.MovieName,
                 MovieDescription = movie.MovieDescription,
                 MoviePrice = movie.MoviePrice,
                 MovieCategory = movie.MovieCategory,
                 MovieYear = movie.MovieYear
                    },
        };


        return View(MovieVM);
    }
}
```